# Pytorch GPU memory allocation error in affine_grid

Tags: memory, pytorch

I have an error:

> CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 9.50 GiB (GPU 1; 23.65 GiB total capacity; 15.96 GiB already allocated; 6.83 GiB free; 15.97 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

It occurs when I try to calculate tensor using **torch.nn.functional.affine_grid.**

I checked memory usage before this line using **torch.cuda.memory_allocated/memory_cached** and got

> Allocated/Cached/Total GPU Memory: 3366.34 MB/3386.00 MB/24217.31 MB

And I manually calculated the size of resulted tensor, which should be exactly 9.5 Gb.
So I don't understand why there are so much already allocated memory (15.96 GiB), I tried to clean up my code and delete all unnecessary tensors but this number didn't changed (while values of memory checks before problematic line did).
Could someone please explain how and why this happens and what can I do with that?